# Listed companies on NASDAQ

Tags: equities, nasdaq

Where can I find a list of listed companies on NASDAQ from 2000 to 2014?

Comment: QA Direct - it is quite expensive though.

Comment: @lowtech seems like a valid answer to me, deserving of an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Bob Jansen:

QA Direct - it is quite expensive though. I've used it in past in the form MS SQL database. It has good enough documentation and query like the one in the question are quite possible to implement in single SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you :) I do have access to Bloomberg - dont you know whether there is a possibility how to find it out?